# Searching Generic Class Field Names

Tags: c#

I have a method which returns a generic list of something.

I want to be able to pass this method a string value which will represent one of the fields in the class's name, and based on this I want to order the data by this field. I want to do this in a different way other than a switch.

For example;

```
private void GetList()
{
    var list = GetResearchStocks("Sedol");
}

private List<Stocks> GetResearchStocks(string orderBy = "")
{
    var currentResearchStockList = _reports.GetZeusData("tblResearchStocks");
    var researchStocklist = currentResearchStockList.AsEnumerable().ToList();
    _zeusResearchStocks = researchStocklist.Select(item => new ZEUS_ResearchStocks
        {
            Sedol = item[0].ToString(),
            StockName = item[1].ToString(),
        }
    ).ToList();

    if (orderBy != "")
    {
        return _zeusResearchStocks.OrderBy(o=>o.) ?????? < What to do here?
    }

    return _zeusResearchStocks;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may either use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library (DLinq) or you may just write an extension method using reflection to use string variables in `order` statements.

For the second option, refer to [this example](http://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/24/orderby-string-in-linq-c-net-dynamic-sorting-of-anonymous-types/).